# Is there a language, compiler or runtime that supports implicit asynchronous programming

Tags: asynchronous

Is there any compiler or runtime that does or is planning to support implicit asynchronous programming.

For example

```
public List<Product> findProductByIdWithSOsAndPOs(int id){

   //The next 3 tasks can be done in asynchronously

   //task 1.a may take a while
   Product product = productRepo.findById(id);

   //task 1.b may take a while
   List<SalesOrder> salesOrders = salesOrderRepository.findAllByProductId(id);

   //task 1.c may take a while
   List<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrders = purchaseOrderRepository.findAllByProductId(id);

   //the runtime is smart enough to know that this task depends
   //on the previous 3 (1.a, 1.b and 1.c) and won't perform this
   //until they are complete without any special syntax (await, 
   //wrapping in future.map, callbacks, etc.)
   //task 2
   Product productWithSOsAndPOs = new Product(product.id, product.name, salesOrders, purchaseOrders);

   //the runtime is also smart enough until all the tasks are complete
   //task 3
   return productWithSOsAndPOs;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are asking for, please explain in your own words what you are looking for. The above is C#, so I assume on Windows? The CLR already has multiple ways to accomplish asynchronous Tasks, and for Parallel programming.

Comment: It can be C# or Java.  I tried to be as generic as possible to make it more understandable.  I'm not really concerned with the language.  What I'm asking is if there is a language that does asynchronous programming without any special syntax.  For example I believe in C# you would use async/await, but instead the runtime can tell what you are trying to run in parallel by the context.

Comment: There are some languages that have parallel programming as a first-order concept. Everything will have 'some level' of syntax.

Comment: Can you list some?

Comment: @decapo See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_concurrent_and_parallel_programming_languages for a launch point (ignore the ones that clearly don't fit the request) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_parallelization. I can't recall the name of the one my friend worked with (it was quite academic at the time), but he also did Charm++ work.

Comment: I think automatic parallelization is the term that I'm looking for.  I just didn't know what to call it.

Comment: I'm confusing parallel with asynchronous.  What I guess I'm asking for is if there is a language that supports programming in the manner I have above in a non-blocking manner and being smart enough to know what it needs to wait for.  In  c# you would use async/await, in node you would use callbacks and in scala you use futures then map them.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET the Tasks.Parallel library makes things pretty natural. There is always some level of syntax involved, but that just comes with the territory. Parallel programming can be tricky, and the compiler cannot always tell exactly what you are doing especially if there are multiple threads involved. Using Entity Framework on your data layer can really make things easy, as the asynchronous calls are generated for you.

Comment: Thanks. This is not really what I'm asking. After looking around more I don't think anyone is doing what I'm asking and I think that's why it's difficult to express. The code I've written above is valid code in a blocking context (i.e. it will return a result if everything is functioning correctly).  However in  a non-blocking environment this code may not return a result. You must add extra code like "await" for it to work reliably, but when I read the code I can understand what needs to run and wait for a result. I'm asking if any language/compiler/runtime supports that natively.